# Autocomplete feature implemented using jquery.autocomplete-min.js conflicts with jquery-ui.min.js

Tags: autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have used  jquery.autocomplete-min.js and implemented Autocomplete feature. It was working good. 
Next, I used jquery.ui-min.js in my project.
Now the Autocomplete feature fails because it is referring to jquery.ui-min.js for Autocomplete.
How can I use them without conflicts?
Is it anything to do with the order?